# EF Core CosmosDb not saving child properties of inheritance hierarchy

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

#### Steps to reproduce

I'm having a setup like for example:

```cs
public Context : DbContext {
  public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
}

public class Animal {
  public string Color { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Animal {
  public int Lives { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal {
  public int Puppies { get; set; }
}
```

I am then adding a Cat and a Dog to my collection (`_context.Animals.Add(new Dog() {...});` and `_context.Animals.Add(new Cat() {...});`

However, in the CosmosDb, the properties `Color` and `Lives` are not saved in the JSON document. Is there a way to allow this?

Thanks.

#### Further technical details

- EF Core version: 3.0.0-preview9.19423.6
- Database Provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos

Comment: You ever get this figured out? I'm trying Entity Framework with Cosmos and I'm also running into this problem.

Comment: No, sorry... I believe I just abandoned the test in the end... :/

Comment: No problem, I believe I figured it out last night. I'll post the answer, maybe it'll help someone else. This stuff is still really new and there's not a lot of documentation out there for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the entities in the OnModelCreating method should solve your problem.

```cs
public Context : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Cat>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>();
    }
}
```